# Are there any available lexical databases for English, containing predicate-argument (relation-role) information?

Tags: python, wordnet

I am looking for a database (something like WordNet) containing predicate-arguments information (also known as relations-roles). I.e. what are the arguments of a given predicate?
For example,

**loves(lover, beloved)**

'*loves*' is a predicate/relation; and '*lover*' and '*beloved*' are the predicate's typical arguments (relational roles).

I am familiar with WordNet, but it contains mainly information about hypernyms and hyponyms.

Are there any available databases containing such information? If there are, it would be perfect if they could be accessed through Python!